# Automated accessibility tests for Compose components similar to Espresso?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

In Espresso, it's easy to write automated UI tests that check for accessibility. Just [enable AccessibilityChecks](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/accessibility-checking). Is there an equivalent for Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Accessibility is something that is possible to do in compose (through semantics), however I don't think there's (at least not yet) a built-in way to automatically test these accessibility features like Espresso's `AccessibilityChecks`